# Actionmailer says email sent but it never gets there (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Actionmailer won't send emails in development, even though they say 'sent' in the console.

gemlist:

```
gem 'send_grid'
```

development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

setup_mail.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port => '587',
    :domain => "heroku.com",
    :user_name => "app123456789@heroku.com",
    :password => "asdfasdfasdf",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    include SendGrid

    def registration_confirmation(user)
        @user = user
        mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered", :from => "media@myemail.com")
    end
end
```

app/views/user_mailer/registration_confirmation.html.haml:

```
Confirm your email address please!

= accept_invitation_users_url(email_token: @user.email_token)
```

console:

```
Sent mail to alain@myemail.com (656ms)
Date: Tue, 11 Feb 2014 13:35:11 -0500
From: media@myemail.com
To: alain@myemail.com
Message-ID: <52fa6d5f667ea_27ce5564820279f3@Ice-box.mail>
Subject: Registered
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-SMTPAPI: {}

Confirm your email address please!
http://localhost:3000/users/accept_invitation?email_token=_JL8DQ2GItxl

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1396ms (ActiveRecord: 192.2ms)
```

Comment: I'm missing something I'm just unsure what it is

Comment: Do you have this in your config: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`?

Comment: You could also check the spam box.

Comment: did it sent without problem in production env? maybe the problem isn't in your app but in sendgrid?

Comment: it sends in production. My main man @roy !!!

Comment: @AlainGoldman did you find solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try setting:

`config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`
 to see if it raises any error on delivery. Otherwise try using other email or check it in you junk folder

Or try this in development mode to check if there is any issues there(it seems fine as you can see the confirmation in the console)

https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener

Comment: How dare you plagiarize me, sir? :)

Comment: i set `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

Add `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` to production.rb or development.rb and restart your app to make the changes working

Comment: that didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

Put this before your smtp settings:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Add ".deliver" at the end where you are calling the email method i.e.:

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
```

It will raise exception that will help you to find the failure cause.

If you are using background job to send email, You can put this snippet in exception block and use [ExceptionNotification](http://smartinez87.github.io/exception_notification/) gem to send email with details which will help you to catch and find the reason of failure easily.